# How can I avoid an error in this .htaccess file?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I have a blog. The blog is stored under the `/blog/` prefix on my website. It has the usual URLs for a blog, so articles have URLs in the format `/blog/:year/:month/:day/:title/`.

First and foremost, I want to automatically redirect visitors to the `www` subdomain (in case they leave that off), and *internally* rewrite the root URL to `/blog/`, so that the front page of the blog appears on the front page of the site. I have accomplished that with the following set of rewrite rules in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite monkey-robot.com to www.monkey-robot.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^monkey-robot\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.monkey-robot.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^$             /blog/               [L]
RewriteRule ^feeds/blog/?$ /feeds/blog/atom.xml [L]
```

That works fine. The problem is that the front page of the blog now appears at two distinct URLs: `/` and `/blog/`. So I'd like to *redirect* the `/blog/` URL to the root URL. Initially I tried to accomplish this with the following set of rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite monkey-robot.com to www.monkey-robot.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^monkey-robot\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.monkey-robot.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^$             /blog/               [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/?$       /                    [R,L]
RewriteRule ^feeds/blog/?$ /feeds/blog/atom.xml [L]
```

But that gave me an infinite redirect (maybe because of the preceding rule?). So then I tried this set:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite monkey-robot.com to www.monkey-robot.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^monkey-robot\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.monkey-robot.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^$             /blog/                       [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/?$       http://www.monkey-robot.com/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^feeds/blog/?$ /feeds/blog/atom.xml         [L]
```

But I got a 500 Internal Server Error with the following log message:

> Invalid command '[R,L]', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

What gives? I don't think `[R,L]` is a syntax error.

Comment: so... you want `/` to go to `/blog/` and `/blog/` to go to `/` ... i'm confused.

Comment: It's not clear either if you want only the root page rewritten (`/blog/` to `/`) or everything under too? For instance, do you want to use `/blog/archives/` or just `/archives/`?

Comment: Just `/blog/` should be redirected to the root, which should look (internally, not via a redirect) in the `/blog/` subdirectory for its file. (Actually, now that I think about it, maybe rewriting to `/blog/index.html` solves the issue...hrm.)

Comment: It still seems like a loop. And I'm still not sure I understand it right. Maybe it will be easier to talk about URLs, not files for a moment. Externally, would an article be available through `www.monkey-robot.com/:year/:month/:day/:title/` or `www.monkey-robot.com/blog/:year/:month/:day/:title/`?

Comment: Articles would be at `/blog/:year/:month/:day/:title/`. *Only* `/blog/` would be redirected to the root (to avoid having two URLs with the same content). I think a loop is created, so any suggestions to avoid that are fine (although the error message seems to allude to another problem).

Comment: "Invalid command" is the message apache would give when a line starts with [R,L]. Could you check if there are no erroneous or "strange" characters? Maybe use "hd vhost.conf" to get a hexdump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you might be able to avoid the infinite loop in your second ruleset by putting the rewriting directives in the main virtual host configuration, not in an `.htaccess` file. That's generally good practice anyway, since rewriting runs a lot faster when you put it in the virtual host, and you can get further speed benefits if you can tell Apache to ignore `.htaccess` files altogether.

The logic behind this is explained in the [mod_rewrite technical documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_tech.html). Here's the gist: as you know, rewrite rules can change which filename a given request corresponds to, and even which directory the resulting file is in. In fact, your

```
RewriteRule ^$ /blog/
```

is a perfect example, which changes the document root to the `blog` directory. But Apache needs to know the directory in order to figure out which `.htaccess` files to check for the request. Maybe you can see the problem here: by the time Apache reaches your `.htaccess` file, it has *already* determined the name of the file it should be accessing, which means it's too late for your rewriting rules to apply.

Apache internally solves this problem by creating a new subrequest, which starts processing over from the beginning, and injecting the rules from your `.htaccess` file into the processing stream so they will apply to the request. As a side effect of this, *all* applicable rewrite rules are applied *again*, and this means that the `[L]` flag is kind of a lie when you use it in a `.htaccess` file. So even though you put `[L]` on your rule to try to force it to be the last rule applied, it really isn't; all the rules are applied again when Apache processes its internal subrequest.

If you don't have access to the main server configuration, you might be able to do this:

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/?$    /           [R,L,NS]
```

The `NS` flag prevents the rule from being applied to subrequests.

Comment: I'll give the `NS` thing a try. Unfortunately, I'm on a shared host so I can't change the main host configuration file. :(

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the comments, I think the most straightforward solution is to **rewrite the root page to the actual file** (`index.html`, I suppose?).

```
RewriteRule ^blog/$ / [R,L]
RewriteRule ^$ /blog/index.html [L]
```

This way looping can be avoided. One problem remains though - the `/blog/index.html` is still **accessible externally**. If that's not an option, I think your best bet is following *David*'s advice and moving the configuration one level up.

Some **alternatives** that came to my mind:

- Leave `/blog/index.html` accessible and use **[link canonical](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394)** (not the best, but easy)
- If server scripting (*PHP* probably) is accessible, redirect `/blog/index.php` to `/` at script level